# How do I clear previous user data on signout in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

If I sign in as a user, and then log out using

```
  Future<void> _signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

but then log back in as a different user, it still shows the previous users credentials.

Is there a way to clear cache on log out so this cannot happen?

I have specific user pages for different users so it's really important that it isn't possible to sign in as the previous user. If I sign out and hit restart on vscode and then log in then it doesn't log in as the other user, and logs in correctly, so I think it's definitely something being held in the cache and carrying over despite logging out.

Comment: How do you fetch the credentials you show about the logged-in user?

Comment: @JesperPaulsen I check firebase auth current credentials and then I have text that displays user.email! and also if the uis = 'userid' I display a certain message

Comment: You will have to rerun that code to get the new `currentUser` value (which will be `null` at that point) and then clear the UID based on that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the correct information about the logged in user, you could use the `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` stream, more info [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state). Every time the auth state changes, for instance when calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`, the stream will emit a new event with either the logged in user or null if the user is not signed in. You can then update your UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was having kinda the same problem. If you print user credentials in every step, you will see you are getting right user from Firebase Auth. But, if you are using provider, the providers are not being updated when you are loggin in again. To solve this, I used the StreamBuilder widget.

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot){
    // return something based on what you get..
  }
)
```